# ol.proj.transform error

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system

I need to do some coordinate transformations on the browser and I cannot figure why I am getting wrong results with Openlayers 3.

Please see the below jsfiddle where I did a sample that defines the EPSG:2321 projection (using the proj4 definition from spatialreference.org) and then transforms a coordinate in that projection to EPSG:4326. Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ak882y4b/

The result should be **32.93843**, **39.96738** (5 digit display precision) whereas ol.proj.transform returns **32.93883**9053463106, **39.96748**782887031. That is quite a large error margin.

What is wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 1):

+towgs84 was missing. The correct projection definition should have been:

proj4.defs("EPSG:2321", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=33 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

Comment: [EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org) has a possibly more accurate transformation, 1784: +towgs84=-84.1,-101.8,-129.7,0.0,0.0,0.468,1.05

Comment: I appreciate the input, but my post proved to be more accurate.